# Magento 2 How should i configurate TAX?

Tags: magento2, tax

i need configuration my tax .

I need this:

Product Price (without TAX) = 322,63 PLN 
Final Product Price = 322,63 PLN + 23% VAT = **419 PLN**

How should I configuration my tax in M2 configuration panel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow steps below to configure Product tax

**step 1)** Login to  Admin and Go to **STORES** -> **Tax Rules**. Click "**Add New Tax Rules**" button

**step 2)**  On New Tax Rule form enter values as below

***Name***     :  23% VAT 
*Tax Rate* :

click "Add New Tax Rates"

Enter tax rates on the new Tax Rate  pop up form as follows

## **Tax Rate**

***Tax Identifier*** :  23% VAT

***Zip/Post Code***  :  *

***State***          :  *

***Country***        :  Select the Country

***Rate Percent***   :   23

Click "**Save**" to save the new Tax rate

**step 3)** Click "**Save Rule**"  button.

**Step 4)** Open the product in edit mode and select

***Tax Class*** : Taxable Goods

**step 5)** Go to Admin **STORES** -> **Configuration** -> under **SALES** tab , Click **Tax**

**step 6)** click "**Price Display Settings**" and select

***Display Product Prices In Catalog*** = *Including and Excluding Tax*

**step 7)** click "**Save Config**"

**step 8)** Refresh Magento cache.

[image]